# demean dataset with categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a problem that should not be difficult to overcome. I have a dataset with both categorical and continuous variables and I would like to demean ONLY the continuous variables (obviously because you cannot demean a categorical variable), using the mean of the entire column.

This is what I have:

```
center_colmeans <- function(x) {
    xcenter = colMeans(x)
    x - rep(xcenter, rep.int(nrow(x), ncol(x)))
}

center_colmeans(Data)
```

However, I don't know how to indicate that I don't want to demean the categorical variables and therefore I get an error. Is there an easy way to solve this?

An example of my dataset could bed (and the variable country is giving me a hard time):

```
Country<- c('BE','BE','DE','GR','IT','ES','DE','NL')
Landvalue<- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 15000,18000,23000,19000,23000)
Temperature <- c('15','16','14','18','23','21','12','15')
Data <- data.frame(Country, Landvalue, Temperature)
```

The output should become (the average of each column is subtracted from each observation per column):

```
Country<- c('BE','BE','DE','GR','IT','ES','DE','NL')
Landvalue<-c(-150, 2250,5650,-6150,-3150,1850,-2150,1850)
Temperature<-c(-1.75, -0.75, -2.75, 1.25, 6.25, 4.25,-4.75, -1.75)
OutputData <- data.frame(Country, Landvalue, Temperature)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your output? Thanks

Comment: The error I get is: Error in colMeans(x) : 'x' must be numeric (due to the categorical variable Country).

What I would like to get is the following dataset: 
Country<- c('BE','BE','DE','GR','IT','ES','DE','NL')
Landvalue<-c(-150, 2250,5650,-6150,-3150,1850,-2150,1850)
Temperature<-c(-1.75, -0.75, -2.75, 1.25, 6.25, 4.25,-4.75, -1.75)
OutputData <- data.frame(Country, Landvalue, Temperature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Data[,sapply(Data,  is.numeric)] <- apply(Data[sapply(Data,  is.numeric)], 2, function(x) scale(x, scale = FALSE))
Data
  Country Landvalue Temperature
1      BE      -150      -0.875
2      BE      2250       0.125
3      DE      5650      -1.875
4      GR     -6150       1.125
5      IT     -3150       3.125
6      ES      1850       2.125
7      DE     -2150      -2.875
8      NL      1850      -0.875
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Would it also be possible to keep the unchanged variable "Country"? Would be very handy for further analyses!

Comment: It is! Thank you very much, both for the quality and the speed of the answer @DatamineR !